# Fancybox - How to show 2 of them

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

-
Hi everyone,

After all, the scenario is the following:

- I have a link that shows a fancybox with a list of tasks
- Inside that I have a link for each task that should show another fancybox

Inside that second fancybox I display the task information such as name, cost, duration, etc etc etc...

But I guess fancybox only allows 1 "box" per document, I'd like to display those 2 boxes but 1 over the over and when I close the task information box, the task list will remain there (because when I click on the information link of one task, the entire box resizes into a new box)

Does fancybox allows these? (1 "box" over other)

Thanks in advance

Javier QQ.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that fancybox so far allows you to do that; the only lightbox I know can do it is [jQuery Tools Overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/multiple.html)